# Библиотека в Java, MathGL

Tags: java

Я только начал учить java после c#, но вот разобраться пока - увы. Мне нужно в моей проге решать различные уравнения (линейные, квадратные, диф. уравнения), хочу использовать библиотеку MathGL (ее используют в С++). Я использую компилятор Eclipse.

Вопрос: подходит эта библиотека MathGL (может есть что-то лучше)? Как подключить библиотеку в Java?

Comment: удивительно, начал учить яву, после шарпа, а сравниваешь с либами их плюсов =)

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека на С/C++ подключается к приложению Java через JNI. В [описании MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_ru/mathgl_ru_7.html#Interfaces) указано, что она уже включает интерфейс для Java:

> Библиотека MathGL имеет интерфейсы к целому ряду языков программирования. Большинство из них базируется на С интерфейсе и построены с помощью инструментария SWIG. Сюда входят Python, **Java**, Octave, Lisp, C#, Guile, Lua, Modula 3, Ocaml, Perl, PHP, Pike, R, Ruby, Tcl.

Но проще, наверное, написать приложение на C/C++ и вызывать его из Java.

Математические библиотеки на Java:

- [Mathematics Library](http://commons.apache.org/math/)
- [High Performance Scientific and Technical Computing](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/)
- [A computer algebra system](http://code.google.com/p/symja/)
- [high-performance, mathematical, Boolean and functional expression parsing and evaluation](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/)

Ну, и можно еще найти, если поискать.

Comment: а не проще вообще все сделать на яве?

Comment: Это зависит от сложности вычислительных задач и сложности интерфейса подключения к библиотеке.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста подробную инструкцию, как подключить библиотеку в Java.

Comment: в первом коменте выложил линку

Answer (score 0):

например,

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int summ = Math.sum(a,b);
```

посмотри методы этой либы, должно помочь

> ```
> import smth_lib.*;
> ```

[тут в картинках](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Comment: Мне надо что бы решать уравнение вышой математики,
Math не подходит,
Ты знаеш как подключать библиотеку к java?

Comment: должен быть аналог решения твоей задачи на яве, без бубна